# jScrollPane loading dynamic content breaks page in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, rss, jscrollpane

I'm loading an rss feed box and applying jScrollPane to it. Works great on my other sites, but for some reason this one is breaking only in Safari. It loads the page correctly and then suddenly snaps to just the rss box all alone. I've tried .delay() and (window).ready thinking it was the timing, and .css(position), to no avail.  Any ideas on why it's doing this?

it's here: miariddle.com/webclient/hundredstories/blog.html

```
scrollpane script:
<script type="text/javascript">         
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(".blog").jScrollPane();

            });
            </script>

CSS:
.blog {
    width: 530px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 380px;
    left: 330px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

html/script that loads the feed:

Comment: this is the feed script: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://output90.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&amp;id=269690&amp;hash=96dab464a684c8bb3b2f0449417da528"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue, and here's what worked for me:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 

jQuery('.blog').jScrollPane(); 

});
```

That is, use (window).load instead of (window).ready as you indicated in your question.

In my case, I had to use jQuery (not $) because of the WordPress script compatibility issues. But in your case it may work with $ as well.

Hope this helps.

P.S. Another thing I noticed, it seems that the .blog div of your site contains only rss feed. jScrollPane is applied to that div, so naturally it applies itself to the content of the div.